LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving: nothing provides requested bzip2 ==1.0.8 he774522_0
I am trying to recreate a conda environment from an environment.yml. The environment.yml looks like this.
name: prompting
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - asttokens=2.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - bzip2=1.0.8=he774522_0
  - ca-certificates=2024.3.11=haa95532_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - comm=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - debugpy=1.6.7=py312hd77b12b_0
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - exceptiongroup=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - executing=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - expat=2.5.0=hd77b12b_0
  - importlib-metadata=7.1.0=pyha770c72_0
  - importlib_metadata=7.1.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - ipykernel=6.29.3=pyha63f2e9_0
  - ipython=8.22.2=pyh7428d3b_0
  - jedi=0.19.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_client=8.6.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=5.5.0=py312haa95532_0
  - libffi=3.4.4=hd77b12b_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h8d14728_1
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - openssl=3.2.1=hcfcfb64_1
  - parso=0.8.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - platformdirs=4.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.42=pyha770c72_0
  - psutil=5.9.0=py312h2bbff1b_0
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pygments=2.17.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python=3.12.2=h1d929f7_0
  - python-dateutil=2.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pywin32=305=py312h2bbff1b_0
  - pyzmq=25.1.2=py312hd77b12b_0
  - setuptools=68.2.2=py312haa95532_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - sqlite=3.41.2=h2bbff1b_0
  - stack_data=0.6.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h2bbff1b_0
  - tornado=6.3.3=py312h2bbff1b_0
  - traitlets=5.14.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.11.0=pyha770c72_0
  - ucrt=10.0.22621.0=h57928b3_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vc14_runtime=14.38.33130=h82b7239_18
  - vs2015_runtime=14.38.33130=hcb4865c_18
  - wcwidth=0.2.13=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.41.2=py312haa95532_0
  - xz=5.4.6=h8cc25b3_0
  - zeromq=4.3.5=h63175ca_1
  - zipp=3.17.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h8cc25b3_0
  - pip:
      - annotated-types==0.6.0
      - anyio==4.3.0
      - certifi==2023.11.17
      - charset-normalizer==3.3.2
      - click==8.1.7
      - distro==1.9.0
      - emoji==1.4.2
      - faiss-cpu==1.8.0
      - filelock==3.13.4
      - fsspec==2024.3.1
      - ftfy==6.0.3
      - h11==0.14.0
      - httpcore==1.0.5
      - httpx==0.27.0
      - huggingface==0.0.1
      - huggingface-hub==0.20.1
      - idna==3.6
      - joblib==1.4.0
      - nltk==3.8.1
      - normalizer==0.0.1
      - numpy==1.26.4
      - openai==1.20.0
      - packaging==23.2
      - pandas==2.2.2
      - pip==24.0
      - protobuf==4.25.1
      - pydantic==2.7.0
      - pydantic-core==2.18.1
      - pytz==2024.1
      - pyyaml==6.0.1
      - regex==2023.12.25
      - requests==2.31.0
      - safetensors==0.4.1
      - scikit-learn==1.4.2
      - scipy==1.13.0
      - sentencepiece==0.1.99
      - sniffio==1.3.1
      - threadpoolctl==3.4.0
      - tokenizers==0.15.0
      - tqdm==4.66.1
      - transformers==4.36.2
      - tzdata==2024.1
      - urllib3==2.1.0

I tried to recreate this environment in an AWS ubuntu machine with
conda env create -f environment.yml
Conda can't solve the environment and gives this error message.
Warning: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file, but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies.  Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they may end up in the wrong place.  Please add an explicit pip dependency.  I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you.
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested bzip2 ==1.0.8 he774522_0
  - nothing provides requested ca-certificates ==2024.3.11 haa95532_0
  - nothing provides requested debugpy ==1.6.7 py312hd77b12b_0
  - nothing provides requested expat ==2.5.0 hd77b12b_0
  - nothing provides __win needed by ipykernel-6.29.3-pyha63f2e9_0
  - nothing provides __win needed by ipython-8.22.2-pyh7428d3b_0
  - nothing provides requested jupyter_core ==5.5.0 py312haa95532_0
  - nothing provides requested libffi ==3.4.4 hd77b12b_0
  - nothing provides requested libsodium ==1.0.18 h8d14728_1
  - nothing provides requested openssl ==3.2.1 hcfcfb64_1
  - nothing provides requested psutil ==5.9.0 py312h2bbff1b_0
  - nothing provides requested python ==3.12.2 h1d929f7_0
  - nothing provides requested pywin32 ==305 py312h2bbff1b_0
  - nothing provides requested pyzmq ==25.1.2 py312hd77b12b_0
  - nothing provides requested setuptools ==68.2.2 py312haa95532_0
  - nothing provides requested sqlite ==3.41.2 h2bbff1b_0
  - nothing provides requested tk ==8.6.12 h2bbff1b_0
  - nothing provides requested tornado ==6.3.3 py312h2bbff1b_0
  - nothing provides requested ucrt ==10.0.22621.0 h57928b3_0
  - nothing provides requested vc ==14.2 h21ff451_1
  - nothing provides requested vc14_runtime ==14.38.33130 h82b7239_18
  - nothing provides requested vs2015_runtime ==14.38.33130 hcb4865c_18
  - nothing provides requested wheel ==0.41.2 py312haa95532_0
  - nothing provides requested xz ==5.4.6 h8cc25b3_0
  - nothing provides requested zeromq ==4.3.5 h63175ca_1
  - nothing provides requested zlib ==1.2.13 h8cc25b3_0

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ bzip2 ==1.0.8 he774522_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ ca-certificates ==2024.3.11 haa95532_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ debugpy ==1.6.7 py312hd77b12b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ expat ==2.5.0 hd77b12b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ ipykernel ==6.29.3 pyha63f2e9_0 is not installable because it requires
│  └─ __win, which is missing on the system;
├─ ipython ==8.22.2 pyh7428d3b_0 is not installable because it requires
│  └─ __win, which is missing on the system;
├─ jupyter_core ==5.5.0 py312haa95532_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libffi ==3.4.4 hd77b12b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ libsodium ==1.0.18 h8d14728_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ openssl ==3.2.1 hcfcfb64_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ psutil ==5.9.0 py312h2bbff1b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ python ==3.12.2 h1d929f7_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ pywin32 ==305 py312h2bbff1b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ pyzmq ==25.1.2 py312hd77b12b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ setuptools ==68.2.2 py312haa95532_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ sqlite ==3.41.2 h2bbff1b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ tk ==8.6.12 h2bbff1b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ tornado ==6.3.3 py312h2bbff1b_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ ucrt ==10.0.22621.0 h57928b3_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ vc14_runtime ==14.38.33130 h82b7239_18 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ vc ==14.2 h21ff451_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ vs2015_runtime ==14.38.33130 hcb4865c_18 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ wheel ==0.41.2 py312haa95532_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ xz ==5.4.6 h8cc25b3_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
├─ zeromq ==4.3.5 h63175ca_1 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
└─ zlib ==1.2.13 h8cc25b3_0 does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel).

I have tried it setting channel_priority to flexible. It doesn't work still. Is there anything else I can try?

As per duplicate, one cannot naively transfer environments across platforms (here win-64 to linux-64). Rather, one usually needs to at least remove build strings, possibly broaden version requirements, and altogether remove any platform-specific packages.
